# Properly set random effect of nested design in gam?

Tags: r, gamm4

I have a set of insect traps, where I have counts of beetles per year. I have several records per each trap and year. I would like to estimate the number of beetles per trap, given several predictors. As the same time, I would like to account for the spatial and temporal autocorrelation, and for a special design for my traps: they are in set of 2 traps (A, B, C..) wher each trap has number 1 or 2. In total I have 8 traps, eg 4 pairs of 2.

How can I account for this 'nested design' in my `gam` model, and considered them as random? My logic is that each trap will be correlated over time to previous year counts, while traps `As` are more sililar then `Bs`.

I have found this post discussing about the claiming [random effects](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2021/02/02/random-effects-in-gams/), but how to claim for both: effect of trap, and a pair of trap?

```
df <- data.frame(my_sum = rnbinom(24, 1, 0.1),
                #  vars ....                   # some environmental variables, likely not needed for this example 
                 location = rep(c('a','b', 'c', 'd'),each =6),  # trap pair
                 trap_n = 1:2,   
                 trap_ID = paste(location, trap_n, '_'),         # individual trap                            
                 year = 1:6)

(df)

m1 <- gam(my_sum ~ s(vars1) + s(vars2) + # predictors skipped here
            s(year) +
            s(location, bs = 're') +  # account for trap pair
            s(location, trap_ID, bs = 're'),  # account for individual trap?
            data = rats, 
            method = 'REML',
            family = poisson)
```

[image]